# How to find mobile model and manufacturer name on server side?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, mobile, user-agent

I need to get the mobile information like mobile model, manufacturer name on server side. How to get it from requesting URL?

For example, User send the request from mobile browser to server for download the jar/jad file. On server side, I need to get the mobile model and manufacturer name and then send the response to mobile based on that mobile model and manufacturer name. How to get these information's(like model name n97 manufacturer name Nokia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)? It's a server-side descriptor file that can help detect various mobile user-agents, capabilities, screen sizes, color depths, etc.

I'm not sure if there's anything out there that would tell you specific model names/manufacturer ATM, but something like the above can at least give you a clue.

Edit: doing further reading...looks like it may be able to give device-specific info in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using [User-Agent Utils](http://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/), you can identify

1. most common operating systems,
2. most common web-browsers,
3. many mobile devices,
4. some tablet devices,

etc.

It has various utility Enums and classes like `Browser`, `BrowserType`, `DeviceType`, `Manufacturer`, etc. to identity. 
It's online JavaDoc can be referred [here](http://user-agent-utils.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/UserAgentUtils/javadoc/index.html).
Download URL for [UserAgentUtils-1.2.3.jar](http://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/downloads/detail?name=UserAgentUtils-1.2.3.jar).